# how to call another activity from thread ?

Tags: android, multithreading

I tried the same questions in stackoverflow  but none of them are working.Someone please help me.
this is my code

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            try{
                                CallSoap cs;
                                cs=new CallSoap();
                               // String resp=cs.Call();
                               String resp= cs.Call();
                                ActivateDecive.rslt=resp;
                            }catch(Exception ex)
                            {ActivateDecive.rslt=ex.toString();}  


                            if(ActivateDecive.rslt=="0"||ActivateDecive.rslt.equals("0"))
                             {
                                 //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Device is not in active state..Please contact admin",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                ActivationText.post(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        ActivationText.setText("Device is not in active state..Please contact admin");
                                    }
                                });

                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                                 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                            ActivationText.setText("Device is Active");
                                            Intent i=new Intent(ActivateDecive.this,FormSelectionACT.class);

                                            startActivity(i);
                                        }
                                    }, 2000);

                             }

                        }
                    }).start();
```

Activity is not comming on top only the included layout is showing...

Comment: Any LogCat you can show? Also have you looked at runOnUiThread, see if that's applicable to you?

Comment: thank you for answering..ya i tried ...but still its not working....there is no reeor in logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to start the Activity from Main Thread. Do it like this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent intent = new Intent (MyActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

taken from here: [How to start an activity from a thread class in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274653/how-to-start-an-activity-from-a-thread-class-in-android)

**edit** Otherwise try to set the handler variable to global, so it should look like this.

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    Handler hander = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(Message m){
            Intent intent = new Intent (MyActivity.this, Next.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
    pubilc void onCreate(Bundle ic)
    {
       //your code setContentView() etc....
       Thread toRun = new Thread()
       {
              public void run()
              {
                    hander.sendMessage(1); 
              }
       }
       toRun.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but still its not working...

Comment: still the same activity is not showing layout.

Comment: thank you now its working...you saved the day..

Answer (score 1):

Finish your Handler method by adding:

```
   ActivateDecive.this.finish();
```

below

```
 startActivity(i);
```

Comment: still its not working.not showing other activity...