# Starting activity from a separate thread?

Tags: java, android

I have an android application that takes a photograph in the main thread and creates a new thread in order to send this image to the server and receives the response. Now, I want to save the information sent by the server in the contact list of my phone, for that I am trying to start an activity on this new thread using the following code:

```
private void addContact() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
    intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);

    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, DisplayName);
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, WorkNumber);
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, emailID);

    this.startActivity(intent);

}
```

but his is throwing me error:
**System Service not available to Activities before onCreate()**

What I think of this message is that since in this new thread it doesn't have any onCreate() method, that is the reason it throws this error.

Can someone tell me how should I start this activity.

Comment: Two questions: (1) What does the `this` keyword refer to in the last line? (2) From what thread are you calling the `addContact() method`?

Comment: my bad. I copied the code from somewhere and forgot to remove this keyword. But I have tried removing this as well. I get the same error. I am calling addContact from a new thread and not the main thread

Comment: try adding contact using new Handler.post

Comment: Do you have some example code as in how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a separate `Thread` to send data to the server, try using an `AsyncTask`:

1. Make the network call in `doInBackground()` and return the server response in a `Bundle` or a `String[]` array to `onPostExecute()`.
2. In `onPostExecute()`, add the server data to the intent and then call `startActivity()`.

Try this. It will work. You are getting an error because you are calling `startActivity()` on another thread. You need to call it on the main (UI) thread.